# I have used this code for populating Checkbox.. But it not Works

Tags: php, yii

```
foreach($add_details_arr as $key=>$val1){

    if($val1 == '1'){
            $ck1=  "checked=>'checked'";
    }else{
            $ck1= '';
    } if($val1 == '2'){
            $ck2=  "checked=>'checked'";
    }else{
            $ck2= '';
    }
}
```

in my view

```
<?php echo CHtml::activecheckBox($model,'setting[0]',array('value'=>'1','uncheckValue'=>null, 'class'=>'radio',checked=>$ck1)); ?>
<?php echo CHtml::activecheckBox($model,'setting[1]',array('value'=>'2','uncheckValue'=>null, 'class'=>'radio',checked=>$ck2)); ?>
```

Comment: try `$ck1=  "checked='checked'";` or simple `$ck1=  "checked";`

Comment: You are using foreach loop, it is not holded the `$ck1` and `$ck2` values if loop has more than one.

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
    foreach($add_details_arr as $key=>$val1){

        if($val1 == '1'){
                $ck1 =  'checked';
        }else{
                $ck1= '';
        } if($val1 == '2'){
                $ck2=  'checked';
        }else{
                $ck2= '';
        }
       echo CHtml::activecheckBox($model,'setting[0]',array('value'=>'1','uncheckValue'=>null, 'class'=>'radio',checked=>$ck1));
       echo CHtml::activecheckBox($model,'setting[1]',array('value'=>'2','uncheckValue'=>null, 'class'=>'radio',checked=>$ck2));
    }
```